# An introduction to nuclei in the pons?

Tags: neuroscience, brain, neuroanatomy, central-nervous-system

I have a couple of questions regarding the nuclei in the pons, thus I figured it would be best to frame the main question in the way that I did.

My main question, however, is **whether the basal pontine nuclei is part of the "cranial nerve nuclei" in the pons or is a separate pontine entity.**

Quoting Kandel's *Principles of Neural Science* (2013),

> The ventral portion of the pons contains the pontine nuclei, groups of neurons that relay information about movement and sensation from the cerebral cortex to the cerebellum.

Quoting Carlson's *Physiology of Behavior* (2013),

> The pons contains, in its core, a portion of the reticular formation, including some nuclei that appear to be important in sleep and arousal. It also contains a large nucleus that relays information from the cerebral cortex to the cerebellum.

And while Wikipedia might not be the best source of information all the time, I must quote a few relevant portions which is causing me confusion,

> A number of cranial nerve nuclei are present in the pons:
>
> mid-pons: **the 'chief' or 'pontine' nucleus of the trigeminal nerve sensory nucleus** (V)
>
> mid-pons: **the motor nucleus for the trigeminal nerve** (V)
>
> lower down in the pons: **abducens nucleus** (VI)
>
> lower down in the pons: **facial nerve nucleus** (VII)
>
> lower down in the pons: **vestibulocochlear nuclei** (vestibular nuclei and cochlear nuclei) (VIII)

I now have broken information about these different kinds of nuclei but I do not know whether the basal pontine nuclei is a part of the cranial nerve nuclei or not.